# Existing file not being read/accessed/located by r

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I have a shiny app to plot a heatmap of the income and other aspects.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(gplots)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Creating a database"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("name", "Company Name"),
      numericInput("income", "Income", value = 1),
      numericInput("expenditure", "Expenditure", value = 1),
      dateInput("date", h3("Date input"),value = Sys.Date() ,min = "0000-01-01",
                max = Sys.Date(), format = "dd/mm/yy"),
      actionButton("Action", "Submit"),#Submit Button
      actionButton("new", "New")),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table")),
                  tabPanel("Download",
                           textInput("filename", "Enter Filename for download"),   #filename
                           helpText(strong("Warning: Append if want to update existing data.")),
                           downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'), #Button to save the file
                           downloadButton('Appenddata', 'Append')),#Button to update a file )
                  tabPanel("Plot", 
                           actionButton("filechoose", "Choose File"),
                           br(),
                           selectInput("toplot", "To Plot", choices =c("Income" = "inc1",
                                                                       "Expenditure" = "exp1",
                                                                       "Compare Income And 
                                                                       Expenditure" = "cmp1",
                                                                       "Gross Profit" = "gprofit1",
                                                                       "Net Profit" = "nprofit1",
                                                                       "Profit Lost" = "plost1",
                                                                       "Profit Percent" = "pp1",
                                                                       "Profit Trend" = "proftrend1"
                           )),
                           actionButton("plotit", "PLOT"),
                           plotOutput("Plot")),
                  tabPanel("Heatmap",
                           actionButton("combine","Combine"),
                           selectInput("ploth", "Plot Heatmap Of", choices =c("Income" = "inc1",
                                                                              "Expenditure" = "exp1",
                                                                              "Gross Profit" = "gprofit1",
                                                                              "Net Profit" = "nprofit1")),
                           actionButton("hplotit","Plot Heatmap"),
                           plotlyOutput("HeatPlot"),
                           plotlyOutput("Next")
                  )
      )
    )

  )
)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output){
  #Global variable to save the data
  Data <- data.frame()
  Results <- reactive(data.frame(input$name, input$income, input$expenditure,
                                 as.character(input$date),
                                 as.character(Sys.Date())))

  #To append the row and display in the table when the submit button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$Action,{
    Data <<- rbind(Data,Results()) #Append the row in the dataframe
    output$table <- renderTable(Data) #Display the output in the table
  })

  observeEvent(input$new, {
    Data <<- NULL
    output$table <- renderTable(Data)
  })

  observeEvent(input$filechoose, {
    Data <<- read.csv(file.choose()) #Choose file to plot
    output$table <- renderTable(Data) #Display the choosen file details
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$filename , ".csv", sep="")}, # Create the download file name
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(Data, file,row.names = FALSE) # download data
    })

  output$Appenddata <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$filename, ".csv", sep="")}, 
    content = function(file) {
      write.table( Data, file=file.choose(),append = T, sep=',',
                   row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE) # Append data in existing
    })

  observeEvent(input$plotit, {
    inc <- c(Data[ ,2]) 
    exp <- c(Data[ ,3]) 
    date <- c(Data[,4])
    gprofit <- c(Data[ ,2]- Data[ ,3])
    nprofit <- c(gprofit - (gprofit*0.06))
    z <- as.numeric(nrow(Data))
    plost <- gprofit - nprofit
    pp <- (gprofit/inc) * 100
    proftrend <- c(gprofit[2:z]-gprofit[1:(z-1)])
    slope = c(((proftrend[2:(z-1)]-proftrend[1:(z-2)])/1),0)
    y = input$toplot
    switch(EXPR = y ,
           inc = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= inc))+
                                             geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                      fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                             ylab("Income")+
                                             theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),
           exp = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= exp))+
                                             geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                      fill = "red")+xlab("Dates")+
                                             ylab("Expenditure")+
                                             theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           cmp = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4]))+
                                             geom_line(aes(y= inc,group = 1, colour = "Income"))
                                           + geom_line(aes(y= exp,group =1, colour = "Expenditure"))+
                                             xlab("Dates")+ ylab("Income (in lakhs)")+
                                             scale_color_manual("",
                                                                breaks = c("Income","Expenditure"),
                                                                values = c(
                                                                  "Income"="green", "Expenditure"= "red"
                                                                ))+
                                             theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           gprofit = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= gprofit))+
                                                 geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                          fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                                 ylab("Gross Profit (in lakhs)")+
                                                 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           nprofit =  output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= nprofit))
                                                +geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                          fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                                  ylab("Net Profit (in lakhs)")+
                                                  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           plost =  output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= plost))
                                              +geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                        fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                                ylab("Profit Lost (in lakhs)")+
                                                theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           pp = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= pp))+
                                            geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                     fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                            ylab("Profit Percentage")+
                                            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),
           proftrend = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot()+
                                                   geom_line(data = as.data.frame(date[2:z]),
                                                             aes(x= Data[c(2:z),4] , y= proftrend,
                                                                 group = 1, color = slope > 0))+
                                                   xlab("Dates")+ ylab("Profit Trend")+
                                                   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
           ))})
  observeEvent(input$combine, {
    Data <<- cbind(read.csv(file.choose()),read.csv(file.choose()),read.csv(file.choose()),read.csv(file.choose()))
    output$table <- renderTable(Data)}) #Display the choosen file details

  observeEvent(input$hplotit, {
    inc1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,2],Dummy2 = Data[,7],Dummy3 = Data[,12], Dummy4 = Data[,17]))
    inc1 <- as.matrix(inc1)
    exp1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,3],Dummy2 = Data[,8],Dummy3 = Data[,13], Dummy4 = Data[,18]))
    exp1 <- as.matrix(exp1)
    gprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,3] - Data[,2],
                                    Dummy2 = Data[,8] - Data[,7],
                                    Dummy3 = Data[,13] - Data[,12],
                                    Dummy4 = Data[,18] - Data[,17]))
    gprofit1 <- as.matrix(gprofit1)
    nprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = (Data[,3] - Data[,2]) - ((Data[,3] - Data[,2]) * 0.06),
                                    Dummy2 = (Data[,8] - Data[,7]) - ((Data[,8] - Data[,7]) * 0.10),
                                    Dummy3 = (Data[,13] - Data[,12]) - ((Data[,13] - Data[,12]) * 0.18),
                                    Dummy4 = (Data[,18] - Data[,17]) - ((Data[,18] - Data[,17]) * 0.22)))
    nprofit1 <- as.matrix(nprofit1)
    date <- as.character(Data[,4])
    h = input$ploth
    switch(EXPR = h ,
           inc1 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(inc1), y = date, z = inc1, type = "heatmap", colorscale = "Earth")),

           exp1 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(exp1), y = date, z = exp1, type = "heatmap", colors = colorRamp(c("red", "yellow")))),

           gprofit1 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(gprofit1), y = date, z = gprofit1, type = "heatmap", colorscale="Greys")),

           nprofit1 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(nprofit1), y = date, z = nprofit1, type = "heatmap")) 
    )

  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

With the ui being like

[image]

Now when i open the app and try to plot the income the following error is shown

```
Error in getExportedValue: cannot open file '~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/viridisLite/data/Rdata.rdb': No such file or directory
```

But when i try to plot the next item(expenditure) in the selectinput the heatmap appears witout any problem and it is pitch perfect of what is exactly needed.

[image]

Moreover when i check the file in the location it appears that the file is present

> /home/mrshekar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/viridisLite/data

What is it that i am missing? Any particular package to extract that folder? Or is that file is supposed to be present somewhere else? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the viridisLite folder from there and then install the package once more. This seems to work just fine. I had a similar problem. If the problem still persists then also delete the normal viridis package and install that also. This will solve your problem. Also update your packages. That also sometimes gives problems.